# PHP IF Function Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement

why does my page redirect to `www.mysite/user/<?php echo $id; ?>`

when my code is:

```
<?php 
$id= $_GET['id'];
$con= $_GET['con'];
?>
```

and

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($con == ''): ?>
<?php
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=<?php echo $id; ?>');
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

it's suppose to redirect to whatever ID equals in the address bar

Comment: Why don't you use a `Location:` header instead?

Comment: Basic PHP syntax: `'`-quoted strings do not interpolate values, and you **CANNOT** nest `<?php` tags inside other `<?php` code blocks.

Comment: You've got some php tagception going on. Might want to take a look at sprintf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=<?php echo $id; ?>');
```

To:

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=' . $id );
```

In your version `<?php echo $id; ?>` is part of the header string.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening two php tags, one inside another while you should concatenate, just change as follow

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user='.$id);
                                                                          //^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user='.$id);
```